# How can I store the "checked" check boxes in a text file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In visual basic I have several check boxes.

All I want to do is storing the ticked/checked boxes in a text file. Like if checkbox1 is ticked it would just write inside a textfile checkbox1  (it's name). Can anyone help me out with this?

I couldn't find anything that would help me do this.

Thanks for helping,

Comment: What part is causing you problems? Do you know how to iterate through controls in a form? Do you know how to get a control's name? Do you know how to write to a file?

Comment: I just don't know how to save the boxes ticked into a text file.

Comment: Please read my comment and notice how I broke the problem down into sub-problems. Which of the sub-problems are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I actually know how to write to a file but the issue is how do i write to the file that for all the "checked" check boxes they get to be written to a text file.